# How does String.Remove() operates regarding memory?

Tags: c#, string, security, memory

I was wondering how does .NET's string.Remove() method operates regarding memory.

If I have the following piece of code:

```
string sample = "abc";
sample = sample.Remove(0);
```

What will actually happen in memory?

If I understand correctly, We've allocated a string consisting of 3 chars, and then we removed all of them on a new copy of the string, assigned the copy to the old reference, by that overriding it, and then what?  What happens to those 3 characters?
If we're not pointing to them anymore, and they're not freed up (at least not that I'm aware of), they will remain in memory as garbage.
However, I'm sure the CLR has some way of detecting it and freeing them up eventually.

So any of you guys know what happens here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the CLR has a garbage collector (that is the actual term) which runs periodically and frees unused objects.

Comment: It sounds like you actually have a question like "How do I securely erase a string from memory?", and you want to know if `string.Remove` is the right way. Perhaps you should ask the former question (as a new SO question) with some details about your specific scenario.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Technically, your'e right, I should've asked a question like the latter, but I understood myself that if the answer to THIS question is GC-related, then it's not secure by any means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `Remove` is going to create a new string that has no characters in it (an empty string).  This will involve the allocation of a char array an a `string` object to wrap it.  Then you'll assign a reference to that string to your local variable.

Since the string `"abc"` is a literal string, it'll still exist in the intern pool, unless you've disabled interning of compile time literal strings, so it won't be garbage collected.

So in summary, you've created two new objects and changed the reference of the variable `sample` from the old object to the new one.

Comment: Did you mean allocation of a char array?

Comment: @Servy, if you check the source code I linked to, `Remove` does create a new string, but with reserved space for the required number of characters.    Essentially, not an empty string.  It then copies the necessary characters into the reserved space.  Everything else is accurate.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch `Remove` doesn't *always* create an empty string.  When you pass `0` as the argument though, you're removing all of the characters, so what is left is an empty string.  You don't need to look at the source code to know that, just the documentation for the method.

Comment: @Servy So from my understanding, in this case, just because I've assigned a literal, they will remain in memory as garbage, but in any other case those chars will be garbage collected, yes?

Comment: @TimorGruber In any other case *if there are no other references to that string* then it *may* be collected whenever the GC *happens* to run next.

Comment: @Servy Yes of course, this is what I meant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

- The method `Remove()` allocates a new string object and returns the results to you
- In your code sample, the `sample` variable is replaced with a new `string` object that no longer has the first character
- When the garbage collector fires, the orphaned string is reclaimed.

Comment: So in terms of security, this is not the correct way of releasing strings from memory regarding tracing issues, am I right?

Comment: @TimorGruber I'm not certain about that, but if you aim at security you should have a look at the [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: What does security have to do with this?  You have a garbage collected language.  The only way to clear a string from memory is to ensure all references to the object are cleared and explicitly invoke the garbage collector.  Garbage collection is by nature ad hoc.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Even doing that wouldn't ensure that the data from the string isn't in memory anymore.  Such is the nature of a garbage collected language.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch It's about the decision weather to store for example passwords in a string during the process of interaction with a database is a good/secure decision or not. If a scenario like I've described earlier behaves the way you've described it, then the answer is no.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Besides, it's always a good thing to increase your knowledge about anything :)

Comment: Info missing from the original question.  In that case I recommend you use @VisualVincent 's solution

Comment: @TimorGruber Are you expecting a hostile user to have access to the system's memory?  If so, then you can't treat that password as secure from such a user, no.  Even `SecureString` likely wouldn't change that.

Comment: Anyone care to comment on why my question was downvoted?  It accurately answers the question, complete with source code to validate the details.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch : Someone's started doing that lately. Someone have downvoted one of my answers too even though it's actually a rather accurate solution to the question. _Who are you mister Mystery Guest?_